# Updating a boolean variable from an imported file

Tags: python, import, boolean, python-multithreading

I'm new to programming and have run into a problem.
An imported function, `bonnie_movement`, is supposed to stop running when the variable `game_end` is True, now when I try to update that variable (which was also imported) in the file where it has been imported to it doesn't update it. Example:

```
import os 
import random 
import threading 
import time 
from movement_testing import * 

def p(): 
    global game_end 
    a = input("> ") 
    if a == "end": 
        game_end = True 
        time.sleep(0.5) 
        print(str(game_end)) 

threading.Thread(target=p).start() 
threading.Thread(target=bonnie_movement).start()
```

The print you see there though gives out `True` but `bonnie_movement` just keeps on going. Does anyone know what I can do?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The variable `a` has nothing to do with the question, it servers no real purpose except stopping the function on declaring `game_end = True` immediately. The print is also as a way to see if `game_end` is updated in the function `p` and serve's no real purpose.

Comment: You should read more about threading and programming in general from python documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same question on reddit and here's the answer:

> Globals in python are global to modules, not across all modules. The line you claim imports the variable actually doesn't.
>
> If 'game_end' is a property of 'Movement_testing' then try accessing it like
>
> movement_testing.game_end = True
>
> and
>
> print(str(movement_testing.game_end))

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the StackOverflow!

If you want to print `True` depending on the value of the `a`, then you don't even need to use the `game_end` variable. In fact, you are already using the `a` variable in a condition.
Now, since I don't know what `game_end` in the `movement_testing` class really does, I will try to guide you with the information you've already provided. You can simply modify your `def p()` function as follows:

```py
def p():
    if a == "end": 
        print(True)
```

Or even

```py
def p():
    print(a=="end")
```

A better approach would be if you could declare the `game_end` variable in this file OR define the `def p()` method inside the `movement_testing`.

Good luck on your journey!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sadly that wasn't what i was asking about, i've edited the post to clear that up, the real question is about how to make the function `p` update the variable `game_end` in the function `bonnie_movement` (both of which have been imported through `from movement_testing import *`).